# Объясните функцию Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

```
def between_markers(text: str, begin: str, end: str) -> str:
    return text[text.index(begin) + 1:text.index(end)]
```

Объясните как реализовали эту функию. Знаю для чего она, но не понимаю ничего после return.

Comment: Это срез (slice), погуглите

Comment: функция на входе получает полную строку и две подстроки, судя по всему начало и конец, и возвращает срез в данном диапазоне

Answer (score 1):

```
return text[text.index(begin) + 1:text.index(end)]
```

Можно расписать так:

```
a = text.index(begin) + 1
b = text.index(end)
return text[a:b]
```

1. Ищем в переменной `text` позицию символа из переменной `begin`
2. Ищем в переменной `text` позицию символа из переменной `end`
3. Возвращаем **срез** (подстроку) переменной `text` от символа, следующего за символом из переменной `begin`, до символа, предшествующего символу из переменной `end`.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def between_markers(text: str, begin: str, end: str) -> str:
    return text[text.index(begin) + 1:text.index(end)]

>>> new_text = between_markers('01234567', '3', '5')
>>> print(new_text)
4
>>> new_text = between_markers('01234567', '0', '5')
>>> print(new_text)
1234

>>> new_text = between_markers('hello world.', ' ', '.')
>>> print(new_text)
world
```